# Memory alignement and Virtual Address Space

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit

I would like to know the relationship between the alignements of virtual and physical memory.

Let's say I have this struct:

```
struct s {
    int16_t a;
    int32_t b;
    int64_t c;
};
```

It's probably laid as:

```
|aa..bbbb|
|cccccccc|
```

And it's size in memory is 16 bytes. It's largest member is `c` (8 bytes) so lets assume it will be aligned on 8 bytes.

Is this alignement enforced on both the virtual memory space AND physical memory space ?

I am wondering if alignement in the virtual address space doesn't matter at all - as long as virtual addresses are actually mapped to aligned physical memory.

Comment: I'd expect `aa..bbbb`

Comment: you're right...

Comment: That would be implementation defined and not something you would usually need to concern yourself with.

Comment: Physical memory is typically committed to virtual memory in large pages, say 4K large. A virtual address aligned to page boundary would map to a physical address similarly aligned to page boundary. Thus, any alignment smaller than the page is preserved.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Great! this sums it up well thanks. So is it even possible to have an requested alignement greater than a page size?

Comment: @PinkTurtle - yes, why not ? with `alignas` can set any `2 ^ n` for struct

Comment: I don't think you can meet large (more than the page size) alignment requirements on the physical addresses (which could be important if you are programming hardware) without involving OS specific requests.